# $C([0,1])$ is not weak* closed in $L^{\infty}(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Show that $C([0,1])$ is not weak* closed in $L^{\infty}(0,1)$

$f_n \xrightarrow[]{weak}f $  is equivalent to $\int f_ng \to \int fg$ for all $g \in L^1$.

To show that $C([0,1])$ is not closed in $L^{\infty}(0,1)$ with respect to the weak topology, we need to find a sequence $f_n \in C([0,1])$ such that its limit is not in $C([0,1])$.

Does this work?

$f_n$ piecewise linear through the points $(0,0), (1/2,0),(1/2+1/n,1),(1,1)$.

Then $|\int_0^1f_ng dx|\leq \int_{1/2}^{1/2+1/n}|g|dx \to 0$, $n \to \infty$

and the limit of $f$ is discontinuous at $1/2$

Comment: Do you mean $L^{\infty}[0,1]$?

Comment: @G.Chiusole In the task it says $L^\infty(0,1)$. I added what I tried above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $L^1$ is meant to be defined with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Take $$f_n : [0,1] \to [0,1], x\mapsto \begin{cases} (2x)^n &: x\in [0,\frac 1 2) \\ 1 &: x\in [\frac 1 2 , 1].\end{cases}$$ It is clear that $f_n$ converges pointwise to the function
$$f (x) = \begin{cases} 0 &: x\in [0,\frac{1}{2}) \\1 &: x \in[\frac 1 2 , 1].\end{cases}$$

Therefore by Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem we have that for every $g\in L^1$ (with $\vert f_n g\vert \leq \vert g\vert$) it holds
$$\int f_n g \to \int fg$$
Therefore we have $f_n \to f$ in your weak sense, but $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: why did you switch from $x^n$ to $(2x)^n$?

Comment: This way the limit function $f$ has no continuous representative in $L^\infty$.